# Write straight C code that uses Foundation types?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, xcode4, llvm

I want to write some straight C code that uses some Foundation types.  For now, I want to use NSInteger, NSUInteger, and NSRange; I can imagine wanting others later.  Is there a header somewhere I can import that will get me these types without causing trouble in a straight C file?

Comment: How do you plan on using them without Objective-C syntax? How do you plan on `#import`ing _anything_ into plain C?

Comment: AFAICT, NSInteger, NSUInteger and NSRange are not dependent on Obj-C syntax. #import-ing might be a little harder.

Comment: No, those specific types aren't. However, their header files are highly interdependent on lots of Obj-C stuff, so it would be impractical to import them. Also it would be trivial to do a custom `typedef struct`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not Foundation, but you can use Core Foundation (`<CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>` or more specifically `CFBase.h`), and the equivalent types `CFIndex`, `CFRange`, etc.